# Getting all possible combinations for powersum problem

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find the all the combinations of numbers which form the power sum. Below is my code and it returns after first combination is found.

`Code:

```
def powerSum(targetSum, N):
    def helper(x,n,c):
        if pow(c,n)==x:
            return [c]
        if pow(c,n)>x:
            return None
        l = helper(x,n,c+1)
        r = helper(x-pow(c,n),n,c+1)
        if l!=None or r!=None:
            if l==None:
                return r+[c]
            else:
                return l
    return helper(targetSum,N,1)
print(powerSum(100,2))
```

Can someone please help me to return all possible combinations
Example:
If input is targetSum =100 and N=2 Output should be list of three possible combination lists =[[10],[6,8][1,3,4,5,7]]
and my output is only [10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconsider the return types:

```py
def powerSum(targetSum, N):
    def helper(x, n, c):
        if pow(c, n) == x:
            return [[c]]

        if pow(c, n) > x:
            return []

        l = helper(x, n, c + 1)
        r = helper(x - pow(c, n), n, c + 1)

        for _r in r:
            l.append([c] + _r)

        return l

    return helper(targetSum, N, 1)

print(powerSum(100, 2))
```

Comment: Nice solution. May want to add comments to elaborate the original code problem?

Comment: @DanielHao thanks. I thought I did -- it's basically the same as the OP's, just with different return types (and consequently the handling for those as well).

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution I'm a bit new to recursion and how to handle the return types and all. I would love to take a suggestion to improve myself